# What does this print(' '*len(msg), end='') call do?

Tags: python

I am studying Python using a book. But there is an example code I don't understand:

```
from time import sleep

for i in range(100):
    msg = '\rProgress %d%%' %(i+1)
    print(' '*len(msg), end='') #I don't understand this statement.
    print(msg, end='')
    sleep(0.1)
```

Actually, I commented out that statement, I got the same result.
Why do I need that statement?

Comment: @trincot no, it's not for indentation.

Comment: The `\r` ('carriage return') code repositions the cursor to the start of the *current* line, so you can re-write it. Does that make it more clear what the author meant to do? See what happens if you count *down* instead!

Answer (score 1):

It is meant to print a series of spaces, to make sure the *previous* line is cleared.

In *this specific case*, that'll never happen, because the message printed will only grow longer (going from 0% to 99%). Moreover, the number of spaces is based on the new message, which would be *too short* if the previous message was longer.

So no, it is not needed here, you found an error in the book.

Comment: Just an aside: I'm slightly wary of a book that's clearly Python 3 (unless there's some future import there) but promotes `%` formatting...